# LWUIT Resource Editor and Netbeans Issue

Tags: java, netbeans, java-me, lwuit

I used the `Resource Editor` to create a really nice application, a search application that searches for businesses from a URL.

I cannot seam to find any tutorial that tells me how to access the `Form Elements` in my forms, I dont even see a code that will allow me manually modify my forms.

Can anyone point me to a tutorial that shows how to Create data driven `J2ME` application using `LWUIT Resource Editor`.?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use finder methods, there were several tutorials in our old blog/youtube channel but I don't have links for them. We have newer tutorials in Codename One which are still applicable for LWUIT e.g. working with form elements in the [How Do I? page](http://www.codenameone.com/how-do-i.html).

Regardless you should probably migrate to Codename One.